# Is there a ReSharper or similar extension for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, resharper

I would like to know if there is some extension to VS Code that helps with cleaning code and suggesting more concise code (i.e., hinting for coding [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)).

Comment: For certain issues I sometimes stumble across a specific Roslyn analyzer that helps, but in general there is no such rich and powerful tool available AFAIK

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a large number of ways to *lint* or provide code suggestions or refactoring tips in VSCode, some [baked-in](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring) or improved with the [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp).

But if I understand your question right, for something akin to an extension to suggest code simplification, like ReSharper, I would point you to the [Roslynator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=josefpihrt-vscode.roslynator) extension. I have used [Roslynator2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=josefpihrt.Roslynator2022) (the Visual Studio 2022 version)  and like how it links you out to see [detailed reasons](https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/blob/master/src/CodeFixes/README.md) about the suggestions it makes.

For formatting your code the [VSCode Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=csharp&target=VSCode&category=Formatters&sortBy=Relevance) has multiple good options such as the [CSharpier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csharpier.csharpier-vscode) extension.

Comment: @DirkBester if you have a better, alternative answer or specific, detailed feedback on why an answer is wrong that's awesome, that's why we are all here, to learn. But attacking people is kind of silly. I've use ReSharper for about six years until I switch over to using Rider every day for development and personally use it to catch dumb mistakes or to automate refactoring. What features are you most frequently using? (The original poster didn't specify, so I took a reasonable guess.)

Comment: I have been irritated over the years by people dismissing intellisense / resharper etc. and at a 100% rate by people that have never used it or tried it. The refactoring and analysis is the most important but only if at the same level of competence. For example, Visual Studio had "refactoring" but as of 5 years ago it could not even change names reliably. I am pleasantly surprised that you actually used it!

Comment: Note to future me. If [SonarLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode) ever adds C# support like it has for JetBrains and VS it would probably be a good candidate to be included. Follow on https://community.sonarsource.com/t/c-support-in-vscode/5888

Comment: I have now spent enough time in VSCode to really miss what Visual Studio with Resharper provided, for C++ specifically. None of this is really doing the same job regardless of the language.

Comment: @Eric D. Johnson -  Sonarlint C# support in beta now: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-for-vs-code-4-0-support-c-analysis-open-sonarqube-issues-in-the-ide/103640